# bootstrap-3 horizontal forms label not staying at the top input fields

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using Bootstrap 3 with .form-horizontal, with the bootstrap classes below, I get forms with the label on top which is what I want. http://bootply.com/73486

However, in Image 2, I try to reduce the width to my  desired size, using classes like .col-lg-*, which suddenly forces the labels to the side instead of remaining on top. I have tried different sizes to no avail..

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> <%= f.label :title %></label>

     <div class="form-control">
       <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => "title" %>
     </div>

 </div>
```

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

However, when I try to wrap inputs in grid columns so as to reduce the width to my  desired size, the labels move to the side of the form inputs instead of on top.

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-lg-2"> <%= f.label :title %></label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
     <div class="form-control">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => "title" %>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please, provide a jsFiddle or Bootply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your first example is correct. To reduce the width without shifting into a form-horizontal style, try wrapping the entire form-group (or the field set) in a smaller div.

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> <%= f.label :title %></label>

         <div class="form-control">
           <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => "title" %>
         </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
`<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label"> <%= f.label :title %></label>

       <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => "title", :class => "form-control" %>

 </div>
</div>`
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for contributing and showing the rails way to do thesame thing as the accepted answer. You have moved the CSS class within the rails form-helper **f.text_field** but it is still essential thesame. Thanks and cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could give the form a col-lg-10 in this case. Since you're actually trying to reduce the form size and not an individual input field this would be preferable.

On the subject of your .form-horizontal usage. If you like the labels on top, you shouldn't use .form-horizontal, just a form without a class. This would fix your problem as well.

In Bootstrap 3 the way .form-horizontal works changed a lot.  The way it now works is by wrapping the form element in a .col-x-x div to give it the desired size and let the labels flow next to it. This has as an advantage to bootstrap 2 that you can easily change the width of the label column.

PS .control-label is not needed anymore